# Почему не вращается камера в Unreal Engine с помощью AxisMappings

Tags: разработка-игр, input, камера, unreal-engine-4, мышь

Сразу скажу, что я только учу Unreal Engine, поэтому вопрос может кому-то показаться немного...

Я хочу чтобы с помощью *мышки* можно было вращать **камеру**, чтобы можно было смотреть по сторонам и вверхв-низ (на пол, на потолок). Камера крипреплена к Pawn следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Я добавил следующие AxisMappings:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть (по крайней мере, насколько я понимаю) будущее вращение камеры влево-вправо соответствует передвижению мыши по оси X, проще говоря влево-вправо, а вращение вверх-вниз - оси Y, проще вверх-вниз.

Окей, на мой Character (первое фото) я написал следующий код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть поворот происходит согласно перемещению мыши.

Результат:

- Вращение влево-вправо работает корректно, согласно задумке
- Вращение вверх-вниз не работает вообще. То есть как бы я не шевелил мышкой, камера не поворачивается и я не могу увидеть небо или пол.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем заключается моя ошибка и как ее исправить?

> P.S. Часто пишут (да и сам пишу), что люди дают очень мало информации по поводу их вопросов. Так что я решил приложить побольше скринов, чтобы было понятней, правда я не знаю как правильно прикладывать код на Blueprint, так что тоже приложил скрином.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить состояние чекбокса "Use Pawn Control Rotation" на компоненте камеры на противоположное. Он в некоторых случаях может вызывать такую проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Не много поздновато, но "Use Pawn Control Rotation" во вкладке Camera Settings необходимо чтобы стояла у компонента SpringArm, а не у камеры. Если будет активировано на камере, то по факту камера будет оставаться на месте, а угол обзора относительно оси координат меняться. А надо, чтобы менялось положение камеры, а не угол обзора. Так правильнее.